# How do I get a datagrid that is bound to an observable collection to notify of deletions using mvvm?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a datagrid which is bound to an observable collection. I would like to know when a row (or multiple rows) are deleted from the datagrid. I'm trying to do this using mvvm.

I'm not worried about properties changing (its all read-only) just deletions. So I know I just need to use the CollectionChanged event. However not sure how I wire this up, especially using mvvm.

**Datagrid**

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
          ItemsSource="{Binding BookList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          Style="{StaticResource DataGridTemplate1}"
          ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_ColumnHeaderCenter1}"                                            
          RowStyle="{StaticResource DG_Row1}"
          CellStyle="{StaticResource DG_Cell1}"                                    
          RowHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_RowHeader1}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          CanUserDeleteRows="True"                          
          Background="Silver"
          RowHeaderWidth="30">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="DatePrice" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding DatePrice, StringFormat={}\{0:dd-MMM-yy\}}" MinWidth="75"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ISIN" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding ISIN}" MinWidth="75"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Name}" MinWidth="75"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Price, StringFormat={}{0:N0}}" MinWidth="75"/>                           
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write something like this. The event occurs when an item is added, removed, changed, moved, or the entire list is refreshed.

```
BookList.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler( BookList_CollectionChanged );

void BookList_CollectionChanged( object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e )
{
    if ( e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove )
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. The event is firing. How do I know which remove has been or is being removed though?

Comment: @mHelpMe Look at the `OldItems` property of the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` event argument. Also, [see this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/07/interpreting-notifycollectionchangedeve.html).

Comment: thanks. I also see if they delete multiple rows i.e. 3 rows the event will be called 3 times

Answer (score 0):

Implement INotifyPropertyChanged

use this

```
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
```

then in your Collection's(ItemsSource of DataGrid) Setter, add

```
OnPropertyChanged("CollectionName");
```